# ReactJS use requestAnimationFrame to debounce on scroll or resize events worth it?

Tags: reactjs, requestanimationframe

Is it worth to use requestAnimationFrame to debounce scroll or resize events if you are using reactjs to do the dom update.

I have an overall immutable object that I am going to update based on the scroll or resize event changes and have reactjs update my dom if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this exact same thing and wasn't able to glean much performance out of it. Instead, the absolute best performance came by using the Twitter approach where you actually just check every 300ms rather than binding to scroll/resize events.

Anytime you bind to scroll/resize events, many browsers will slow down a lot, even if you're not doing much. In my situation, lazily loading images, this works way better.